# Map a key to open terminal and execute commands

Tags: shortcut-keys, ssh

I want to map a key, say ctrl-shift-m to open a terminal, ssh into the mailhost, open pine and go into the compose mail pane. I already have ssh-key setup so i dont have to type my password while doing ssh, so that is not an issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I do when I need:

**1) Make a script with all commands needed**

*Example:*

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh user@server.etc

ssh some-command

others-commands

exit 0
```

**2) Create the shortcut**

Run `gnome-control-center keyboard` then go to "Shortcuts" > "Custom" > "+"

[image]

Name: Anything
Command: `gnome-terminal -e "bash -c \"/path/to/script ; exit ; exec bash\""`

Change "/path/to/script" for the correct path, and

delete "exit" if you don't want the terminal to close after the execution of the script.

Then choose the shortcut you wish.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 3):

you can open terminal and execute command via the following code

`gnome-terminal --COMMAND=string`

You can add key mapping in

`Applications > Keyboard > Shortcut > Custom`